# Bit manipulation, unnecessary mask?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm trying to get a hold of bit manipulation in embedded c programming.

I have the following code

```
#define X_POS       (8UL)
#define X_MASK      (0x1FUL<<X_POS)
#define Y_POS       (16UL)
#define Y_MASK      (0x3UL<<Y_POS)

typedef struct {         
    uint32_t  res[6];  
    uint32_t  config[10];                            
} myStruct_type;

myStruct_type myStruct;

void configure (uint32_t n, uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    myStruct.config[n] &= ~(X_MASK | Y_MASK);     // A
    myStruct.config[n] |= ((x<<X_POS) & X_MASK) | ((y<<Y_POS) & Y_MASK);  // B
}

int main (void)
{
    configure(3, 18, 2);

    while (1) { }
}
```

I understand that the line marked with the comment A is used for setting the bits of interest to 0, i.e. clearing the bits.

Also I understand that on the line marked with B the bits of interest are set to wanted values.

But what is the purpose of the X_MASK and Y_MASK on line B??? Aren't the values set by

```
(x<<X_POS) | (y<<Y_POS)
```

Comment: To make sure that only requested bits are set.

Comment: BTW: no need for `UL` in `#define X_POS       (8UL)` and `#define Y_POS       (16UL)` - the `UL` serves no purpose as it does not affect the type of the shift result.  `#define X_POS   8` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the masking on line B is to ensure that only the bits you want set will be set. e.g. if x is `0xFFFFFFFF`, the `&` with `X_MASK` will stop the bits above what you are interested in from being set.

So assuming config[0] starts out at 0, x is 0xFFFFFFFF and y is 0, without the maskingin  line B, you would have

```
myStruct.config[0] &= ~(X_MASK | Y_MASK);     // config[0] is still 0
myStruct.config[0] |= (0xFFFFFFFF << 8) | (0<< 16);  
// config[0] is now 0xFFFFFF00
```

with the masks, the second line is

```
 myStruct.config[0] |= ((0xFFFFFFFF<< 8) & 0x1F00) | (( 0 << 16) & 3 << 16);  // B
```

which is

```
myStruct.config[0] |= 0x1F00 | 0);
```

Comment: Is this the common way to do it? Another way could have been to check x and y before. If they where out of bounds an error message could have been returned.

Comment: Yes either way works, but it is normal to do it in the function whatever since the mask doesn't cost much performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use `(x<<X_POS) | (y<<Y_POS)` you simply assign the values `x` and `y` shifted to the left.

The mask eliminates the unwanted bits. For example:

```
X_MASK = 0x1FUL << 8UL = 0x1F00000000 = 0b111110000...
```

With the logical & (AND) you set all bits to zero that are zero on your mask:

```
X_MASK     0b00000001111100000000.....
x<<X_POS   0b01010101010100000000.....
&          ________________________
result     0b00000001010100000000.....
```

On a higher level you can say, that the `X_MASK` sets all bits of `x` to zero except the lowest 5 and the `Y_MASK` sets all bits of `y` to zero, except the lowest 2. Afterwards your result gets bit shifted to the left. So the mask will clear the higher bits.